# Add another background image via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background

I would like to add another background image to my div element, however I dont want to simply write over the existing one, I would like to have multiple backgrounds, so it should add the new background url below the first.

Here is the what the original CSS will look like..

```
#cover-art {
    background:
        url('http://beta.mysite.net/img/banner1.png') top left no-repeat,
    padding:250px 0 0;
}
```

What I would like to do via jquery is add another image url line below the first one like this...

```
#cover-art {
    background:
        url('http://beta.mysite.net/img/banner1.png') top left no-repeat,
            url('http://beta.mysite.net/img/banner2.png') top left no-repeat,
    padding:250px 0 0;
```

}

Also something to note is that #cover-art css is in an external style sheet.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you need to make that comma after no-repeat a semi-colon at the end of your background-image property (in both code blocks).

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson It actually was in my original code, but I copied the first line for the second image, as it was easier to copy and paste rather than alter lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go. Keep in mind this won't work with a lot of browsers that are more than a couple years old:

```
var _oCurr = jQuery('#cover-art');
var _sBg = _oCurr.css('background-image');
_oCurr.css('background-image', _sBg + ', url(/img/banner2.png)');
```

Comment: I've recreated this in jsfiddle, check here: http://jsfiddle.net/YtysX/1/
I cant get it to work

Comment: The majority of your problems stem from bad CSS. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/YtysX/4/

Comment: Don't forget that the background-image property is entirely different from the background property. You can't tack on positions, repeats, etc. If you are using multiple backgrounds, I highly recommend you use separate statements to declare positions, repeat, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var $el = $('#cover-art');
var bg = $el.css('background-image'); // old image
$el.css('background-image', bg +','+ 'img/banner2.png'); // add new image
```

Comment: that didnt do the trick, tried both just the url as well as the the whole line

Comment: This is almost right. You need to wrap the path to images in url(...) as I have in my example below.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Last I checked, you can't have two background images on 1 element.</s>
CSS3 allows you to do so but it won't work on some browsers.
[Here's a chart of compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds).

I suggest you create another element inside `#cover-art` and apply the same CSS to its child except for the background image.

So for example

```
<div id="covert-art">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

`#child'`s background image would be above the parent (`#cover-art`)

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gavjw/) as an example.

Comment: You absolutely can have multiple background images.

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson You're right. With CSS3... but lots of browser won't support it.

Comment: If you said that two years ago, I'd agree with you. Now somewhere around 90% of browsers support it. I wouldn't call the number of browsers that don't support it a lot; I'd call that hardly any. For easy reference here are the main browsers that don't support: IE8 and below, Safari 5.0 and below. And that's it. Firefox has had it since FF3 iirc, Opera and Chrome have had it since forever (exageration) but they auto update and there is almost nobody using older versions.

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson I agree with you, that's why while you were writing the comment, I changed 'a lot' to 'some'.

Comment: @ComputerArts I am aware that multiple backgrounds will not work on older browsers, but from looking at my GA I can see there arent many people using older browsers to access my site anyway so to make it easier on myself I have chosen to adopt multiple backgrounds