# js/css add multiple backgrounds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have seen several usages of the .css() function or simply setting element.style.background in js

what i want is to stack multiple backgrounds, ie add another background over the 1st one.

i tried

```
input.style.background.add("white url('http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/5/5JuDgOa.png') no-repeat 30px 6px;");
```

but the add function is not recognized :

> TypeError: input.style.background.add is not a function

i guess i could set the css after onload with "background1", then reset it as "background1, background2" and back to "background1" when i need to but i would prefer an **add() / remove()** approach

Comment: you want to apply this changes to an input ?

Comment: add the background images in one call, separated by commas. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds

Comment: maybe you could do a carousel with a 1sec delay ; or create various divs on the same position, and different z-index, and change this property with a js function

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738668/add-another-background-image-via-jquery

Answer (score -3, accepted):

why not create a few classes :

```
.bg-1{bg-img ...1}
.bg-2{bg-img ...2}
```

and use

```
.addClass('bg-1');
```

and

```
.removeClass('bg-x');
```

etc... with a js function with the wanted delay

Warning :

Jquery functions apply to jquery objects, for you :

```
$(input).addClass('some-class');
```

Comment: nice but it doesn't work:
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    input.addClass("customSearchInputLoading"); that returns : TypeError: input.addClass is not a function

Comment: if you use Jquery as mentionned in your tags, you CAN use addClass() : `$('#input').addClass('my-class')`  you have to use it on Jquery objects : for you : `var input = document.getElementById('input'); $(input).addClass('stuff here') `

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 allows web designers to specify multiple background images for box elements, using nothing more than a simple comma-separated list.

**How it Works**
Multiple background images can be specified using either the individual background properties or the background shorthand property.

*The sintax*

```
background-image: <bg-image> [ , <bg-image> ]*

<bg-image> = <image> | none
```

example: `background-image: url(sheep.png), url(betweengrassandsky.png);`

See these 2 examples:

```
#exampleA {
width: 500px;
height: 250px;
background-image: url(decoration.png), url(ribbon.png), url(old_paper.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left top, right bottom, left top;
}


#exampleB {
width: 500px;
height: 250px;
background: url(left.png) left top no-repeat, url(right.png) right top no-repeat, url(main.png) left top repeat-x;
}
```

So, if you want to add multiple backgrounds using the jquery function css(), just follow the syntax above using an object inside the css().

```
.css({
   'background-image' : 'url(decoration.png), url(ribbon.png), url(old_paper.jpg)',
   'width' : '400px'
});
```

Comment: thanks i was able to make that work with a js function that reset the input style, but i'm more in search of what singe batteur is saying, with a defined class that i can add or remove when i want

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: solution found:

```
function SetSearchEngineLoadingStyle()
{
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    $("#input").removeClass("customSearchInputLoaded");
    $("#input").addClass("customSearchInputLoading");
}

function SetSearchEngineLoadedStyle()
{
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    $("#input").removeClass("customSearchInputLoading");
    $("#input").addClass("customSearchInputLoaded");
}

.customSearchInputLoading {
    background: red url("http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/5/5JuDgOa.png") no-repeat 8px 6px;
}
.customSearchInputLoaded {
    background: white url("http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/5/5JuDgOa.png") no-repeat 8px 6px;
}
```

ok now it gets trickier, i want to add a simple css animated loader as a background image (instead of url("http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/5/5JuDgOa.png")) in the loading class ;-)

i'll do some research but any comments are appreciated

thanks for the help

well this a partial answer i guess ;-)

the lead from singe batteur works using addClass on the jquery object

the css

```
.customSearchInputLoading {
background: red url("http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/5/5JuDgOa.png") no-repeat 8px 6px;
}
.search input {
background: white url("http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/5/5JuDgOa.png") no-repeat 8px 6px;
}
```

the js:

```
    $("#input").addClass("customSearchInputLoading");
(basically during the ajax call)
    $("#input").removeClass("customSearchInputLoading");
(on ajax success)
```

so you see i am trying to simply switch the input background color to red during the ajax call then back

this works because i see in firebug that the class is added and removed, but visually it doesn't turn red...

fyi the lead from Yuri Ramos works with:

```
SetSearchEngineLoadedStyle();
SetSearchEngineLoadingStyle();

function SetSearchEngineLoadingStyle()
{
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    input.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    input.style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/5/5JuDgOa.png")';
    input.style.backgroundPosition = '8px 6px';
    input.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
}

function SetSearchEngineLoadedStyle()
{
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    input.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    input.style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/5/5JuDgOa.png")';
    input.style.backgroundPosition = '8px 6px';
    input.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
}
```